# ¿Cómo crear un archivo .csv en un servidor usando sftp?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, sftp

**Transfondo:**

He desarrollado una aplicación de escritorio de tipo Windows Form en C# usando Visual Studio Community 2015, el cual consulta cierta información de una base de datos en Access para luego guardar dicha información en un servidot a través de sftp.

**Problema:**

Estoy usando el siguiente código<sup>1</sup> para guardar el archivo *(en este caso, usando **ftp**)* el cual es funcional:

```
try
{
    // Credenciales de prueba:
    string rutaArchivo = @"C:/MiArchivo.csv";
    string FTP_server = "N/A";
    string FTP_username = "N/A";
    string FTP_password = "N/A";

    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(rutaArchivo))
    {
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stream.ReadToEnd());

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(FTP_server + nombreArch);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTP_username, FTP_password);
        Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No se guardó el archivo: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Pero, al usar **sftp** me genera el siguiente error:

> No se guardó el archivo: System.NotSupportedException: No se reconoce el prefijo URI.
>      en System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
>      en System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)

De acuerdo con la siguiente [fuente](https://www.codeproject.com/answers/665367/csharp-sftp-download-and-upload#answer4):

> SFTP - not support by .NET out of the box. You'll need a third party support.

He buscado varias alternativas, como:

- [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/lang:es) del cual estoy leyendo la documentación, pero no estoy familiarizado con este componente *(estoy revisando otras fuentes de información que me orienten cómo puedo usar este componente en mi proyecto)*.
- Renci.SshNet y SSH.NET lo cuales me redirigen a la misma [página](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/).

Además, para instalar, necesitaría descargarla a través de [NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2015), pero los comentarios de otros usuarios muestran que la aplicación es inestable.

Estoy buscando la manera mas "sencilla" para guardar un archivo usando **sftp** y/o un "paso a paso - tutorial" de cómo puedo descargar cualquiera de estos componentes para implementar en el presente proyecto.

---

<sup>1</sup> Código modificado de la siguiente [fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296613/4092887).

Comment: tu servidor soporta sftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código utiliza la librería de `Renci SSH.Net` la cual es sencilla de implementar:

```
using Renci.SshNet;
using System.IO;

namespace YourProjectNamespace
{
    public class sftp
    {
        public static void UploadSFTPFile(string host, string username,
        string password, string sourcefile, string destinationpath, int port)
        {
            using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
            {
                client.Connect();
                client.ChangeDirectory(destinationpath);
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourcefile, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                    client.UploadFile(fs, Path.GetFileName(sourcefile));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**La llamada al método `UploadSFTPFile`:**

```
string source = @"FilePath and FileName of Local File to Upload";
string destination = @"SFTP Server File Destination Folder";
string host = "SFTP Host";
string username = "User Name";
string password = "password";
int port = 22;  //Port 22 is defaulted for SFTP upload

sftp.UploadSFTPFile(host, username, password, source, destination, port);
```

El código de ejemplo es extraído desde el blog de [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1111060/Upload-File-to-SFTP-Site-with-Csharp-in-Visual-Stu)

En el [siguiente link](http://www.sftp.net/client-libraries) podrás encontrar diferentes clientes para conectarse vía `SFTP` para .Net, algunos de ellos son de paga.